# disable KeyBoard shortcuts on JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, jwplayer

We want to disable Keyboard shortcuts to fast forward and seek another position.
Javascript disabled keys are working when it is not in fullscreen but we are facing issues when it is full screen.

Is it possible to turn off keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code demo that demonstrates how to disable the left and right keyboard arrow keys:

```
      jwplayer('player').on('ready', () => {
        // BLOCKING LEFT and RIGHT KEY PRESS
        let all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (let element of all) {
            element.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
                if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 37) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                };
                if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 39) {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                };
            }, true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more succinct approach that targets the jwplayer element(s) directly and disables all keyboard shortcuts:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.jwplayer').forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => e.stopImmediatePropagation(), true);
});
```